# NoSQL big data which project to use for CDR storing?

Tags: mysql, open-source, nosql, bigdata

I am working in a large telecom company and i wish to store many CDR (Call Detail Records). It should be a huge database. I wish to try to push some OpenSource solution. I am very familiar with MySQL, but i thought maybe to try something different that should be robust and easy to scale. Any recommendation on a stable OpenSource NoSQL solution? - MongoDB? Hadoop? Cassandra? Any other idea? Maybe i should stick to MySQL?

Please note that i will need the option to query like, how many minutes a specific phone number was talking.

What is the most called number.

Etc'.

A mysql table would look like this:

```
   timestamp   TIMESTAMP
   from_number CHAR(12)
   to_number   CHAR(12)
   duration    MEDIUMINT
```

Comment: This is a very subjective question and really boils down to peoples opinions so I am gonna say MongoDB, you can shard nicely on the schema you have provided and it would be very easy to pick out computers for log viewing etc.

Comment: Like the previous comment says this is very subjective. But here is my favrourite NOSQL overview page: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Comment: I also work for a telecom and I don't think NoSQL can do well with CDR storage. If I think about the further billing logic, then I find it too complicated. With NoSQL you'll have to prepare each invoice exactly at the moment CDR is being stored into the DB, and I would say that this will not be the fastest action, especially for Pre-Paid systems.

Comment: I'd be inclined to stick with what you know. Your usage of NoSQL could get complicated as the project grows, and upon your departure possibly leave the firm with an expensive stack to work with. Have you analysed how easy it is to hire that sort of expertise in your location? (I'd push this question up the chain if I were you, so it doesn't explode back at you later on!)

Comment: IMHO you should stay with mysql, relational db has much better storage format for CDRs than a document/nosql database (think about the overhead from storing field names in every record). And if mysql is too slow then you should resort to a low-level db implementation tailored for your queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you could probably build a CDR solution with any database backend, one challenge will be in how you approach your data modelling and querying.  NoSQL data modelling requires a significantly different approach compared to relational data, and is more akin to a denormalized data warehouse (which should be a good fit for your use case!).

There are a number of open source CDR projects which may also be worth investigating depending on your requirements.

For a specific example that may help with your investigation, I would have a look at [CDR-Stats](http://www.cdr-stats.org/):

- [How it works](http://www.cdr-stats.org/documentation/how-it-works/) includes a high level overview of the product architecture
- [Datastore architecture](http://www.cdr-stats.org/docs/en/latest/html/mongodb-architecture.html) describes their approach to data modelling and pre-aggregation using MongoDB

Further viewing:

- [CDR-Stats call data analysis for Asterisk & Freeswitch](http://www.slideshare.net/areski/cdrstats-voip-analytics-solution-for-asterisk-and-freeswitch-with-mongodb)
- [Building a data warehouse of CDR records: Solution Considerations](http://datamgmt.com/building-a-data-warehouse-of-call-data-records-cdr-solution-considerations/)
- [Hadoop-based data mining platform for the telecom industry](http://vimeo.com/7671465)

Answer (score 2):

CDR processing involves very large volumes of records which also increase over time. 100% increase per year is not uncommon. I have found that it is good idea to separate the collection from the reporting and forward collected data, as records or aggregates, to an appropriate reporting engine. See [BDsafe](http://www.dt2pte.com/) for an overview and case study. I have delivered systems which have ben running for several years and handle several billion CDRs per day continuously. In summary, I doubt you will find 1 system to serve all your needs, however, I am sure you can achieve your goals with a little lateral thinking. First, store your data efficiently (cheaply) and then you can play around with different reporting engines for different purposes. If you can supply me with some general cases you have to deal with, I would be happy to explain what I have done in those cases. I have been focused on this area for telcos and LEAs for over 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

CDR's will proportional to the number of calls that lands. I dont think MySQL is the best solution for this as data will be ever growing. I am really doubtful about the performance as your data grows.
This is under the assumption that you might have to store the data for at least 1 year as regulatory norms etc.
Stennie suggestion of CDR-Stats looks good. They are using MongoDB